# My PowerShell script only works when running from ISE

Tags: powershell, cmd, scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I can't post all of the script contenet, but the basic idea is that it downloads JSON and converts it to objects using the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet. Some objects are filtered out, and the rest are written to an XML/XLS document (in the Excel 2003 format). This file is then attached to an email and sent to various people.

The problem I'm having is that it only works when run from the Powershell ISE. Once I try setting up a scheduled task, calling it from cmd, or even calling it from powershell, the attached file is completely empty. It is as if some functions do not run (the one that loops through and creates all rows).

I can continue to run from ISE for the time being, but the idea of this script is to send out an automatic email that will require no intervention. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: You need to figure out where the break is happening. Is your scheduled task running PoSH v2 or v3? You say "It is as if some functions do not run" - you need to **test this**! Put a statement in every function to write out to a log file indicating that the function has been entered. There really isn't enough here for us to diagnose. Do you get anything in the Windows event logs?

Comment: If it doesn't work calling it from Powershell, then run it in the local scope by dot-sourceing it ( . ./script.ps1).  That will leave all the variables resident in the session and you can start examining them to see where it fell down.

Comment: I was able to get it working. Turns out I defined a variable using another variable that was defined later in the script. After moving it, it began to work again. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the script "dot sourced" 
which can be done like this

```
powershell.exe -noexit -file c:\test.ps1
```

or

```
pwershell.exe -noexit ". c:\test.ps1"
```

See this link under the -File section 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from the comments to the original post, it seems that the script was (unexpectedly?) working in the ISE because of the bug/quirk/feature that allows scripts run in the ISE to be aware of variables used in the console window and vice-versa.

This can often cause logic problems or unexpected results when a script runs with a variable already defined (and not initialized carefully in the script).

Ways to avoid this problem:

- Try to test your code in as clean an environment as possible.

> http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2015/02/12/getting-a-clean-powershell-environment.aspx
>
> To make sure a script runs in a completely clean test environment, you
>   could of course restart the PowerShell ISE. A more convenient way is
>   to open another PowerShell tab: in the PowerShell ISE, choose File/New
>   PowerShell Tab.

- Use `Set-StrictMode 2` in your script to catch undefined variables, etc.

> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx
>
> `Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0`
>
> - Prohibits references to uninitialized variables (including uninitialized variables in strings).
> - Prohibits references to non-existent properties of an object.
> - Prohibits function calls that use the syntax for calling methods.
> - Prohibits a variable without a name (${}).

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem be for and for me executing the scrip using single-threaded function from powershell worked.
You could also try some other options, go to this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx) to find more info.

Example

```
powershell.exe -noexit c:\test.ps1 -sta
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the missing variable or function to global.

```
function global:mycall{}
```

Answer (score -1):

Start your Script with:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it